# Windows Identity Framework Single Sign out Problem

Tags: wif, single-sign-on

I a using below code for Single Sign out,
http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/12/wif-ws-federation-and-single-sign-out.html

Problem which i am facing is, it printing the RP's name on the Default.aspx page of my STS Application, I want as soon as User Click on Sign out user should redirect to Some Common Page, Which would be Home Page of Some RP, But when i do Response.Redirect on default.aspx of STS after completing Signout Process, it it did not perform Single Signout process,

Can any one help in this issue,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sign-out is done the following way:

1. Click "Sign out" on a RP's page.
2. Show sign out page of STS with image "links" to all currently signed in RP's.
3. The browser requests the images of every RP. This request includes the parameter `wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0` which does a sign out on the RP.

Step 3 only works if the sign out page of the STS is displayed in the browser. By calling `Response.Redirect` you prevent this. A possible solution could be to redirect the user after e.g. a second to the target page. This can be done through javascript or a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, i notify RP's in some different way because i did not want to show the Images of every RP, and did not want to stay user for some time on default.aspx of STS.